# How to run LoadPartial function for first item in dropdown list when loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a function which when the dropdown is changed - it loads a partial view. Code:

**Html:**

```
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedCustomerId, new { @id = "dropdownlabel" })
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCustomerId, Model.CustomerIDItem, new { @id = "customId" })
</p>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#customId").change(function() {
                var id = $(this).val();
                $('#divValues').load('@Url.Action("DefaultValuesPartialView", "DefaultValues")?selectedCustomerId=' + id, function (response, status, xhr) {
                    $("#divValues").html(response);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Which works perfectly. It loads the partial view (updates a table on the page when the dropdown is changed without reloading the entire page. What I want to do is that when the dropdown is loaded it should load the item selected first as well.

My first thought was that it would be something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("#customId").onload(function() {
                    var id = $(this).val();
                    $('#divValues').load('@Url.Action("DefaultValuesPartialView", "DefaultValues")?selectedCustomerId=' + id, function (response, status, xhr) {
                        $("#divValues").html(response);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

But obviously it didn't work, any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @brothers28 Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just trigger `change` event on page load

```
$(function() {
    $("#customId").change(function() {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $('#divValues').load('@Url.Action("DefaultValuesPartialView", "DefaultValues")?selectedCustomerId=' + id);
    }).change(); //trigger change event on page load
});
```

Note: You don't need to use `$("#divValues").html(response)` as `.load()` function already does it for you.